# Delegates not working

Tags: swift, delegates

I'm writing code to connect to BLE devices and then list them in a table to connect or disconnect from them. I'm happy with the peripheral and manager roles and understand how to access the BLE device. Previously I've used NSNotifications but would rather ruse delegates to manage notification.

My code below is simple, in terms that it scans for devices and then prompts a delegate, but the delegate is not responding.

Please help...

Delegate

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

protocol BLEDelegate {

    func bleDidConnectToPeripheral(sender: BLEDiscovery, peripheral: CBPeripheral)

}

let bleDiscoverySharedInstance = BLEDiscovery()

//MARK: - UUIDS for StingRay Genessis M (SRG)
let StingRayGenesisMUUID    = CBUUID    (string: "346D0000-12A9-11CF-1279-81F2B7A91332") //Core UUID


//MARK: - UUIDS for StingRay Genessis HR (SRG)
let StingRayGenesisHRUUID   = CBUUID    (string: "F9AB0000-3F75-4668-9BAC-F8264DAE7820") //Core UUID

//MARK: - Device and Characteristic Registers
var BLEDevices          : [CBPeripheral] = []           //Device Array
var BLECharDictionary   = [String: CBCharacteristic]()  //Characteristic Dictionary


class BLEDiscovery: NSObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate {

    private var centralManager : CBCentralManager?

    var delegate: BLEDelegate?

    override init() {
        super.init()

        let centralStingRayBLEQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.stingray", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)
        centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: centralStingRayBLEQueue)


    }

    // MARK: - CB centralManager
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager) {
        switch (central.state) {

            case CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOff:
                print("CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOff")

            case CBCentralManagerState.Unauthorized:
                // Indicate to user that the iOS device does not support BLE.
                print("CBCentralManagerState.Unauthorized")
                break

            case CBCentralManagerState.Unknown:
                // Wait for another event
                print("CBCentralManagerState.Unknown")
                break

            case CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOn:
                print("CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOn")
                self.startScanning()

            case CBCentralManagerState.Resetting:
                print("CBCentralManagerState.Resetting")

            case CBCentralManagerState.Unsupported:
                print("CBCentralManagerState.Unsupported")
                break
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Start scanning for StringRay devices with the appropriate UUID
    func startScanning() {
        if let central = centralManager {
            central.scanForPeripheralsWithServices([StingRayGenesisMUUID,StingRayGenesisHRUUID], options: nil)
        }
    }

    // MARK: - CB Central Manager - Did discover peripheral (follows : startScanning)
    func  centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : AnyObject], RSSI: NSNumber) {

        delegate?.bleDidConnectToPeripheral(self, peripheral: peripheral)

        //Check if new discovery and append to BLEDevices where required
        if BLEDevices.contains(peripheral) {
            print("didDiscoverPeripheral - ALREADY DISCOVERED   ==", peripheral.name)
        }
        else{
            BLEDevices.append(peripheral)
            print("didDiscoverPeripheral - NEW DISCOVERY        ==", peripheral.name)
        }
    }

    // MARK:  - CB Central Manager - Connect and Disconnet BLE Devices

    func connectBLEDevice (peripheral: CBPeripheral){
        //Connect
        self.centralManager!.connectPeripheral(peripheral, options: nil)
    }

    func disconnectBLEDevice (peripheral: CBPeripheral){
        //Disconnect
        self.centralManager?.cancelPeripheralConnection(peripheral)
    }



}
```

Delegator

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

class MainViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource, BLEDelegate {


    //MARK: - View Object Links
    @IBOutlet weak var deviceTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var infoBlockView: UIView!

    // MARK: - Interface Builder Inspectables
    @IBInspectable var BorderWidth : CGFloat = 0.75
    @IBInspectable var BorderRadius : CGFloat = 5.0
    @IBInspectable var BorderColor : UIColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        formatDeviceTableView()
        formatInFoBlock()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

    func bleDidConnectToPeripheral(sender: BLEDiscovery, peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        print ("Its alive == ", peripheral.name)
    }

    // MARK: - View Fomrating

    func formatInFoBlock(){
        infoBlockView.layer.borderColor = BorderColor.CGColor
        infoBlockView.layer.cornerRadius = BorderRadius
        infoBlockView.layer.borderWidth = BorderWidth
    }


    // MARK: - TableView Functions

    func formatDeviceTableView() {

        deviceTableView.layer.borderColor = BorderColor.CGColor
        deviceTableView.layer.cornerRadius = BorderRadius
        deviceTableView.layer.borderWidth = BorderWidth

    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        //Define a cell and assign it to DeviceTableCellTableViewCell class and use the reuse identifier from IB - "deviceCell"
        let cell = deviceTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("deviceCell") as! DeviceTableCellTableViewCell

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        cell.deviceNameLabel.text = String(indexPath.row)

        return cell

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        print("Row Selected ::", indexPath.row)
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        print("Accesory Selected ::", indexPath.row)
    }


}
```

I expect the code just to print out "Its alive..." to show me that it is working...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You're more likely to get useful answers if you provide a minimum example which demonstrates the issue, the code you give above is very lengthy. As a gut instinct though, you may not be setting your `delegate` property on your `BLEDiscovery` class. It's optional, and I can't see any code where it's set, which would lead to it failing to do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In the Delegate file in `var delegate: BLEDelegate?;` add "weak" to it:

`weak var delegate: BLEDelegate?;`

2. Move `let bleDiscoverySharedInstance = BLEDiscovery();` from the delegate to the delegator.
3. To finish add: `bleDiscoverySharedInstance.delegate = self;` into the viewDidLoad to let it know that is the delegate.

If you want in the link below you have a really similar example to follow using delegates: https://bitbucket.org/vicrius/flickr-visualizer/src

Hope all that helps.

Comment: If you want to use a few for this kind of things I recommend you to check NSNotificationCenter which will be better for this cases. Is even simpler to use. Good Luck!